# Требуется помощь с составлением запроса в Python!

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка

У меня сейчас проходит практика и мне попалась задача с составлением кода для задачи. Код я сделал и объяснил, но преподаватель сказал упростить код. К сожалению попытки составить новый, успехом не увенчались поэтому прошу помочь. Вот код программы, который у меня получился и сама задача:

Задан одномерный массив целых чисел. Образуйте из него два отсортированных по возрастанию массива, содержащих четные и нечетные числа. Подсказка: четное число делится на 2 без остатка.

```
a = [152, 412, 63, 94, 125, 956, 907, 800]
b = [(i) for i in a if i % 2 == 0]
b.sort()
print('Чётные числа массива а:',b)
c = [(i) for i in a if i % 2 == 1]
c.sort()
print('Нечётные числа массива а:',c)
```

Comment: Подсказка:  здесь два прохода по списку, а достаточно одного.

Comment: почему у вас код программы в виде скриншота? почему не в текстовом виде?

Comment: @strawdog код я составил 4 дня назад, и делал в онлайн компиляторе. После этого я сделал скриншот кода и приносил преподавателю в колледж

Comment: то есть, вы предлагаете нам набрать код за вас?

Comment: @strawdog 
a = [152, 412, 63, 94, 125, 956, 907, 800]
b = [(i) for i in a if i % 2 == 0]
b.sort()
print('Чётные числа массива а:',b)
c = [(i) for i in a if i % 2 == 1]
c.sort()
print('Нечётные числа массива а:',c)

Comment: Можно делать операции в другом порядке, их понадобится меньше )

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [152, 412, 63, 94, 125, 956, 907, 800]
print('Четные', [x for x in a if x % 2 == 0])
print('Нечетные', [x for x in a if x % 2 == 1])
```

Comment: а сортировка по возрастанию ?  #написано в задании.

Comment: @Sergei спасибо за помощь, только надо было перед Print`ом поставить a.sort()

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [152, 412, 63, 94, 125, 956, 907, 800]
print('Четные', sorted([x for x in a if x % 2 == 0]))
print('Нечетные', sorted([x for x in a if x % 2 == 1]))
```